# React On loops open modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi Im on my way learning reactjs, now I faced difficulties with Modal in loops.

My issue is, my modal is not showing.

Here is my current code :

```
state = {
    modal: false,
    modal_backdrop: false,
    modal_nested_parent: false,
    modal_nested: false,
    backdrop: true,
};

toggle = modalType => () => {
    if (!modalType) {
        console.log(this.state.modal);
        return this.setState({
            modal: !this.state.modal,
        });
    }

    this.setState({
        [`modal_${modalType}`]: !this.state[`modal_${modalType}`],
    });
};

render() {
    let bookItems = [];
    let modalItems = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < 17; i++) {
        bookItems.push(<Col lg="3" md="6" sm="6" xs="12" className="mb-3">
            <a href="#" onClick={this.toggle()}>
                <Card inverse color="dark">
                    <CardBody>
                        <CardTitle className="text-capitalize">
                            <center>{i}</center>
                        </CardTitle>
                    </CardBody>
                </Card>
            </a>
        </Col>);

        modalItems.push(<Modal
            isOpen={this.state.modal}
            toggle={this.toggle()}
            className={this.props.className}
        >
            <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle()}>{i}</ModalHeader>
            <ModalBody>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            </ModalBody>
            <ModalFooter>
                <Button color="primary" onClick={this.toggle()}>
                    Do Something
                </Button>{' '}
                <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.toggle()}>
                    Cancel
                </Button>
            </ModalFooter>
        </Modal>);
    }
```

How can I show modal with specific id ? Because my modal currently not working.

Im using this https://github.com/reduction-admin/react-reduction template.

Any help will appreciate.

Editted

This is my current return code:

```
 return (
        <Page title="Modals" breadcrumbs={[{ name: 'modals', active: true }]}>
            <Row>
                <Col md="12" sm="12" xs="12">
                    <Card>
                        <CardHeader>Modal</CardHeader>
                        <CardBody>
                            <Row>
                                {bookItems}
                            </Row>
                                {modalItems}
                        </CardBody>
                    </Card>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </Page>
    );
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: just at a glance you may want to revisit all these `this.toggle()` calls you have and try making them `this.toggle` if `toggle` is supposed to happen in response to an action

Comment: I modify into this.toggle(`$({i})`) also not showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are not showing what your render function returns. Does it return the modal array?

To show the modal with current id, pass in the id when the component is first created inside the loop:

```
this.toggle(id, modalType)
```

And change the function signature to

```
toggle = (id, modalType) = () => {
  this.setState({
  currentId: id,
  [modalType]: !this.state[modalType],
}
```

This will create a new closure function that stores the id and modalType inside each button, and when clicked, will trigger the correct setState. You can then use the currentId stored in state inside your modal.

Comment: Edited answer - need to see what render function returns.

Comment: Hi I edited my code it works, showing the modal, but... the Id in modal header is always showing 16.`<ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle(i)}>{i}</ModalHeader>`.  How can I return selected Id ?

Comment: hmmm - try to change `for (var i = 1; i < 17; i++) {` to `for (let i = 1; i < 17; i++) {`, and also use currentId in state rather than i from your for loop. `<ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle(i)}>{this.state.currentId}</ModalHeader>`

Comment: So you should make sure that id is bound to the calling function in each Card:

` <a href="#" onClick={this.toggle(id, modalType)}>`

and when clicked, sets bound id into currentId in state, then use this.state.currentId in your modal to make sure you're using the correct id.

Comment: Ohh that `currentId` it can be called inside state. Now I know. its work! Thanks a lot buddy

Comment: Exactly, no problem!